# How to make a script accessible to root user?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, sudo, root

A regular user can run this script, but root can't find it.

I have a simple script that I have saved in `~/bin`. I updated the `.profile` file to include this folder in the PATH. I can go into terminal, be working in any directory, type the name of the script and it runs fine.  But if in that terminal I switch to root, the script cannot be found.  I assume there is some file somewhere which needs a new $PATH update, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `sudo`, which is probably the case, there is a security policy that modifies the $PATH environment variable to a *secure path* (defined in the file */etc/sudoers*). The *~/bin* directory isn't included in the default *secure_path* set in the *sudoers* file, so running `sudo script` wouldn't work, but `sudo ~/bin/script` would.

You can place the script in one of the folders defined in the *sudoers* configuration file (i.e. */usr/local/bin*) to make it directly accessable. The *secure_path* can also be changed on the configuration file, though it's not recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for the first answer not recommending to bypass SECURE_PATH. Indeed, either placing the script into a location included in the SECURE_PATH (owned and only writeable by `root` of course) or, if absolutely necessary and you know what you're doing, specifying the full path is the right and secure way to go.

Answer (score 2):

To temporarily prevent `sudo` from resetting your path to `secure_path`, for a single command, without modifying any global configuration, you can do:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH command
```

Where `command` is the name of the executable you want to run that is in your `PATH`.

You could make an alias for this and add to your own (not root's) `~/.bashrc`... something like

```
alias sudo2='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

Then you could use `sudo2 command` to run an executable file with `sudo` using your own PATH.

Comment: +1 for the `alias` solution! Simple way to solve the issue without having to touch the default sudoers config

Comment: @ByteCommander I try to operate without using `sudo`.  This includes, so that my personal space don't get changed away from my normal login access.  I only use `sudo` when I want to make system changes.  So I don't want to operate as `root`.  However, if my account were compromised, my system would be at the mercy of whoever compromised it.  I won't remove my account form sudoer.  I take measures to not have my account compromised.  I won't fool myself into thinking a person can have access to my account and not also have root access.  I don't share my account or my passwords with anybody.

Answer (score 0):

**Why the script fails when run by root?**

You have to check the path of the effective user... in this case `root`.

Run this:

(The first two lines are the prompts plus the commands.  The last line is the output of the command.)

```bash
$ sudo su -
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

**Recommendations for where to place your script to be run by others:**

Make a subdirectory under `/opt` for your project and place your project's exec scripts there.  This is a place that will survive an OS fresh install on the same partition (minus formatting of course).

The root area for your scripts can be in:

```
/opt/myprojectname/myscriptfiles/
```

Now you can link your scripts `/usr/local/bin/` with

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/myprojectname/myscriptfile/myscript.sh /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`
```

You won't have to change the the `root` $PATH variable, because as you can see from the test above, it's already there.

So rather than changing the root path, you can change your path to search the `/opt/myprojectname/myscriptname`

Alternatively, you could link your `~/bin/myscript.sh` to `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for a more permanent solution so that the scripts I write can still be accessed even when i have to be doing things as root.  I have been using your suggested export command, but it becomes tiresome to do it each time I open a terminal.  I guess I expected that, as can be done for the local user, the root user would have a file to which the directory could be added.

Comment: @dhp904 Use the last alternative... the `sudo ln -s ~/bin/myscript.sh /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`.  That will make it available to both you and to root.

Comment: Sorry, but I see a **huge** security risk there! You add a location to `root`'s `$PATH` where a normal unprivileged user has full write access. This allows the user (or any malware/hacker that managed to get this access level) to place their own executables there or modify existing ones, waiting for them to get executed as root accidentally. There is a reason why `sudo` always resets the `$PATH` variable even when preserving the rest of the environment. I must recommend to avoid bypassing this.

Comment: Your alternative 2 is not better, it should be the other way round (original file in `/usr/local/bin`, owned by `root` and no write permission for others and a symlink to that file in `~/bin` - although that would not be necessary for anything). Otherwise you again have the problem of an executable that is owned/writeable by a normal user but likely to get executed with root privileges.

Comment: @ByteCommander I would expect the file is owned by the author and only writable by author.  It appears like he's working on the script and need quick access to check his changes.   With the alternative 2 he's not setting a root path.   He's setting a root file that he along can make changes to.  If another user can write to the file, the would be able to write to it even in the `/usr/local/bin` which is accessible by root.  I would recommend his local files and local installed programs be in a directory that won't be clobbered during a new OS install.

Comment: "He alone" is enough to open a big opportunity for privilege escalation. Of course it can be done if you want a quick and dirty solution and don't care about security. It should not be done for that exact reason though, at least not in a production environment.

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm editing and formatting the answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the priviledged environment is not the same as that of the user, and for good reasons. There are mainly two solutions: (i) call your scripts with their path, or (ii) chown your scripts to root and move them higher in the file hierarchy (say, /usr/custom/bin but whatever works), then update the user's PATH, rather than trying to do the contrary.